# Is there a way to send messages to people with stack exchange?.if so how?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Please help.i want to send a message to my friend but I do not know how

Comment: This is not the place for sending messages.  That's what email is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As fbueckert's comment indicates, this site does not have a private messaging system, so your options for getting in contact with your friend are limited to the following:

1. Leaving a public comment. If it's regarding something completely off-topic, this is not the place to do so.
2. Inviting him to one of [the site chats](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=gaming.stackexchange.com), maybe opening up a room just for the two of you. This is more appropriate if you want to discuss things that are off-topic, but again, any messages sent could be viewed by other users on the site.
3. Emailing/messaging him outside of this site. This is the best option if you want to contact him about something private/off-topic.

Answer (score 13):

There is no *private* messaging feature on Stack Exchange sites. However, you do have a few options.

First of all, many people put some form of contact info in their **user profile**, which you can access by clicking on their name at the end of any of their answers or comments.

If you're responding to a particular question, answer, or comment by that person, you can also **add a comment** to the post in question. If you want to ensure that your message reaches a particular user, you can prepend **@Username** to 'ping them, as so:

> @LessPop_MoreFizz This answer is stupid, and you're stupid. And also wrong. But mostly stupid.

If you did that in the comments section of any question or answer I've written or commented on previously, I'll be **pinged**, and see your message in my inbox the next time I visit a StackExchange site.

Finally, many more active users of StackExchange sites regularly use **[Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com)**. Arqade's main 'lobby' style chat room is [The Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge), which is where you'll find many of us hanging out. Chat, like comments, includes a **Ping** functionality that works the same way. Simply write a message beginning with **@Username**. If that person has been in chat recently, they'll see the ping.

Comment: As a side note, **DON'T** leave a comment like the example presented.  It will get deleted very quickly.

Comment: @MBraedley As an example, however, it brings the point across, and is worth +1 all on it's own.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Exchange is not a social networking platform. If someone has their email or other information listed in their profile, that is the only way you have of contacting them directly. (I suppose you could ping them in chat, but that is hardly the place for private messages and conversations, being a public room and all that is supposed to stay generally related to the site's topic.)